# Terms & Conditions - ESP - Google Schemas

Tags: google-schemas

I wanted to know if as an Email Service Provider, is there a way to give all of our users (only big organizations) the chance to use these features, for transactional or promotional emails.

Thanks

P.S.: Each organization has its own domain for sending.

Comment: To send an email with Google Schemas to add action buttons

Answer (score 1):

They would need to be registered individually by Google. If you're interested in helping them register for action buttons in email you can read about how to do that [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/registering-with-google).

Also, please note that these features are only allowed for specific transactional emails and are not meant for bulk promotional emails.